# Kendo MVC TreeList not Rendering from Initial BindTo

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-treelist

My `MVC ViewModel` contains the initial list of records to be displayed within my `Kendo` `TreeList`.  However, the TreeList is NOT rendering the initial list...and I don't understand why.

REQUIREMENTS:

- If initial records exist...display them
- The READ ACTION CANNOT be executed on the initial render (other controls manage that later)

For other Kendo controls, you set:

- AutoBind(false)
- BindTo(Model.MyCollectiom)

...and the READ ACTION does not execute.  But the TreeList is failing at the moment.

**MY RAZOR LOOKS LIKE:**
At initial render records DO EXIST (see image below)

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeList<DeviceHierarchyDataItem>()
              .Name("treeTarget")
              .Columns(columns =>
              {
                  columns.Add().Field(e => e.DisplayName)
                               .TemplateId("tmplDisplayName")
                               .Title(" ");
              })
              .BindTo(Model.TargetDevices)
              .AutoBind(false)
              .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                         .Read(read => read.Action("find", "devicehierarchy", new { Area = "" })
                                           .Data("window.etp.pageController.getFilter"))
                         .ServerOperation(false)
                         .Model(m =>
                         {
                             m.Id(f => f.Id);
                             m.ParentId(f => f.ChildOf);
                             m.Expanded(true);
                             m.Field(f => f.DisplayName);
                         }))
              .Sortable())
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: In plain JS we do that by referencing the data object like `dataSource: { data: myData }`, no sure if `BindTo()` does that behind the scenes. I would suggest you to check if a `.Data()` method exists in asp.net mvc dataSource's(I have looked into docs but could not find a good doc for asp.net dataSource tho).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strangely enough the TreeList MVC control doesn't support binding to local data...
At least not in [july 2018](https://www.telerik.com/forums/bind-treelist-to-local-data)...

The recommendation is to use the [jquery control](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treelist/local-data-binding) instead.

And then convert the data from the Model to a json string:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                var dataSource = new kendo.data.TreeListDataSource({
                    data: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model.TargetDevices)),
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                        id: "Id", 
                        parentid: "ChildOf", 
                        expanded: true
                        }
                    }
                });
```

I hope it helps!